# Set same distance for all objects inside a Windows Form

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, user-interface

I would like to set the same distance "x" from the TabControl border for all labels inside my Windows Form. This distance "x" must be the same in Tab1, but also in Tab2, Tab3, etc., so basically the same value globally. How can I achieve this result? Is there something similar to a grid like for Photoshop?

[image]

Comment: Form has a Padding property. Make it say 20. After set tab control to Dock.Fill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `TabControl` padding to adjust the distance and in the designer as you drag your labels round they'll snap with little blue lines to the edges at the same distance.

[image: Example of blue snapping lines]

Alternatively, you could use a `TableLayoutPanel` or `FlowLayoutPanel`, set them to Dock Fill and put the labels in that way.

[image: Example of TableLayoutPanel with 1 column and 2 rows]

Comment: Could you also tell me how to overwrite the default auto-distance (when the blue line appears) between two labels?

Comment: I've updated the answer slightly. The padding is what impacts the distance.

Comment: So basically you are saying that, if I want the same padding distance between all labels (not between label and border), I would have to manually set it for each label I add?

Comment: It works for that also, yes. You can copy and paste a previously set up label or add all the labels and edit them in a batch to make it easier (ctrl click to select multi). Also look at the `Margin` property to see if that is more what you need. I would suggest the `TableLayoutPanel` approach as it might make your life easier, though.